# Set Accessibility Identifier in UIView Extension

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview

I worked on Mobile Test Automation.Previous, some elements don't have any identifier but i need to import identifiers for testing issues.

So I decide to write an extension to UIView, hereby that code will be affect all codes so I wont need to add one by one.

How can I do ? Should I write on init or awakeFromNib ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cant affect all your project but you can add a func to UIView/UIViewController init func lets call it "initIdentifiers" and override it in all the views you would like  to assign accessibilityIdentifier to.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you'll want to have specific accessibility identifiers for elements you want to expose to the accessibility system.

You can set those directly in Storyboards/Interface Builder, or you can set them in your view's initializer when implementing UIs programatically:

```
class MyView: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.accessibilityIdentifier = "my-custom-view"

        let label = UILabel()
        label.accessibilityIdentifier = "my-custom-label"
        self.addSubview(label)
    }
}
```